# OmniSupervisor Skills Backlog Summary - Not show all Pending Routings

Tags: omnichannel, omni-supervisor, skill-based-routing

We are setting up Omni channel using Skill based routing via an Omni Flow, and have multiple skills configured.

However, only some of these are showing on the Omni Supervisor 'Skills Backlog'.
2 visible here:
https://app.screencast.com/mBhyZaFdUxatE

However, if I check the PendingServiceRouting object there are 3 as I would expect
https://app.screencast.com/YgIgkJm71jNd3

It seems that the skills of English_Speaker and French_Speaker are showing fine, but any on CH are not showing as expected here.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing at a skill level here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was on the Supervisor Configuration.
I had previously explicitly selected the original skills I created like below:
https://app.screencast.com/vqW9DIUztAtKt

Solutions here are either move all skills to selected, or select none which automatically applies all